Orientable surface with constant principal curvatures has either umbilical point or non-positive gaussian curvature
I need to show that if an orientable surface S has constant principal curvatures, then either each point of S is umbilical or the Gauss curvature of S is non-positive everywhere.
I believe I can start off the proof by stating that if $k_{1} = k_{2} $, then each point is umbilical since they are constant. Then, I consider the $ k_{1} < k_{2} $ case.
I think I can prove this by contradiction and assume that every point is elliptic (Positive gaussian curvature) everywhere, and then take advantage of the fact that a point $ p \in S $ is elliptic iff there is some $ p_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{3} $ such that $ \vert p - p_{0} \vert^{2} $ reaches a max at p.
However, I can't figure out a way to make the same $ p_{0} $ work for all $ p \in S $. If I could, then S must be a sphere and have only umbilical points, achieving a contradiction.
Does anybody know what I should do at this step of the proof? Or if my approach is even in the right direction.

In fact, a connected surface with both principal curvatures constant must be (a subset of) either a sphere, a plane, or a right circular cylinder. See Exercise 17 on p. 66 of my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile.

HINT: I suggest you apply the Mainardi-Codazzi equations.

@ ThreeMilks: What is an example with constant principal curvatures in a negative Gauss curvature surface? Also for a sphere the curvatures should not be arbitrary constants but be also  equal in  magnitude when all points are umbilicals ..right?

Assume the principal curvatures of $S$, $k_1,\,k_2$ are constant and $S$ has no umbilical points (so $k_1>k_2$). We'll in fact prove that $K=0$.
Since $p$ is non-umbilical, there exists an orthogonal parametrization of a neighborhood of $p$, i.e, has the first fundamental form coefficient $F=0$ and, additionally, has second fundamental form coefficient $f=0$. In this case, the principal curvatures can be written as:
$$\begin{align*}k_1=\dfrac{e}{E}\\\\k_2=\dfrac{g}{G}\end{align*}$$
where $E,\,G$ are coefficients of the first fundamental form and $e,\,g$ of the second fundamental form. Now, taking partial derivatives gives
$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{\partial k_1}{\partial v}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial e}{\partial v}E-e\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial v}}{E^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial e}{\partial v}-k_1\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial v}}{E}\\\\\dfrac{\partial k_2}{\partial u}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}G-g\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}}{G^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial u}-k_2\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}}{G}\end{align*}$$
Applying Codazzi-Mainardi equations, in this setting gives
$$\begin{align*}\dfrac{\partial k_1}{\partial v}=-\dfrac{1}{2E}(k_1-k_2)\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial v}\\\\ \dfrac{\partial k_2}{\partial u}=\dfrac{1}{2G}(k_1-k_2)\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}\end{align*}$$
Since $k_1,\,k_2$ are constants, this in particular gives us
$$\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial v}=0=\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}$$
Actually, this is true for every point of $S$, so the above derivatives are identically zero. By Gauss' equation, one can prove the following formula for Gaussian curvature (in this parametrization)
$$K=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{EG}}\cdot\left[\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{EG}}\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial v}\right)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{EG}}\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial u}\right)\right]$$
Plugging in the derivatives yields
$$K=0.$$

This is an unnecessary proof by contradiction. Just assert/prove that at non-umbilic points we must have $K=0$.

I also noticed that the argument fails in the last step of plugging the partial derivatives being zero... I'm trying to fix it now.

No, your argument is correct.

I agree there is no need for a lengthy proof, but it was your comment with a hint of using Mainardi-Codazzi equations that reminded me of some results and I wanted to use them in my very first answer here at m.se :).

Your proof is fine. Just rephrase and eliminate the unnecessary contradiction, as I suggested. :)

Well done. :) …
